# DoS due to infinite renegotiation during read or write

Tags: ssl, openssl, polling, starvation

Does OpenSSL and/or the SSL/TLS protocol provide some kind of built in protection against infinite renegotiation?

In particular, is it possible for `SSL_read()` to continue executing forever because the remote side (possibly maliciously) keeps requesting renegotiations without sending payload data?

I am worried about this because I want to service a number of SSL connections from a single thread using a polling mechanism and also ensure a form of fairness where the processing of I/O on one connection does not lead to starvation of I/O on the other connections.

When I call regular `read()` on a socket in nonblocking mode, I know it cannot keep executing forever, because the buffer will fill up eventually.

However, since `SSL_read()` can handle renegotiations transparently, it seems to me that if the remote side (possibly maliciously) keeps requesting renegotiations without sending payload data, and the underlying transport layer is fast enough to make the underlying reads and writes never fail with `EWOULDBLOCK`, then `SSL_read()` could end up executing forever, and thereby starving the other connections.

Therefore my question: Does OpenSSL or the protocols have mechanisms for avoiding that? The question applies equally to `SSL_write()` by the way.

EDIT: For example, can I be sure that `SSL_read()` will return with an `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`/`SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` indication before engaging in multiple renegotiations, even if the underlying read/write operations never fail with `EWOULDBLOCK`?

EDIT: For the purpose of this question, assume that I am using a regular socket BIO (`BIO_s_socket()`) and that the underlying socket is in nonblocking mode.

Comment: It can't handle renegotiations transparently. It relies on you calling write when NEED_WRAP occurs.

Comment: I'm guessing OpenSSL does not provide a heuristic to detect it. Its likely a remediation that needs to occur higher in the stack and at a network boundary, like a firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in protection in OpenSSL. But you can use `SSL_CTX_set_info_callback` or similar to set a function which gets called on each negotiation. This way you can cut the connection if too much renegotiations happen inside the same connection. See [Protect against client-initiated renegotiation DoS in OpenSSL/Python](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115847/protect-against-client-initiated-renegotiation-dos-in-openssl-python) for more information.